# How can I get Apache2 in OpenSUSE to map /srv/www/htdocs/index.php to localhost?

Tags: apache-httpd, opensuse

If the document root for Apache in OpenSUSE is `/srv/www/htdocs` and that folder only contains my website with its own `index.php` file, entering "localhost" in a browser should take you to the homepage.

**It doesn't!**

It takes you to the It works! page instead.

Since there is no index.html file in that folder, what is changing the document root to point somewhere else and where is it pointing to?

This is the output of httpd.conf minus a huge block of comments at the top:

```
### Global Environment ######################################################
#
# The directives in this section affect the overall operation of Apache,
# such as the number of concurrent requests.

# run under this user/group id
Include /etc/apache2/uid.conf

# - how many server processes to start (server pool regulation)
# - usage of KeepAlive
Include /etc/apache2/server-tuning.conf

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_log

# generated from APACHE_MODULES in /etc/sysconfig/apache2
Include /etc/apache2/sysconfig.d/loadmodule.conf

# IP addresses / ports to listen on
Include /etc/apache2/listen.conf

# predefined logging formats
Include /etc/apache2/mod_log_config.conf

# generated from global settings in /etc/sysconfig/apache2
Include /etc/apache2/sysconfig.d/global.conf

# optional mod_status, mod_info
Include /etc/apache2/mod_status.conf
Include /etc/apache2/mod_info.conf

# optional cookie-based user tracking
# read the documentation before using it!!
Include /etc/apache2/mod_usertrack.conf

# configuration of server-generated directory listings
Include /etc/apache2/mod_autoindex-defaults.conf

# associate MIME types with filename extensions
TypesConfig /etc/apache2/mime.types
DefaultType text/plain
Include /etc/apache2/mod_mime-defaults.conf

# set up (customizable) error responses
Include /etc/apache2/errors.conf

# global (server-wide) SSL configuration, that is not specific to 
# any virtual host
Include /etc/apache2/ssl-global.conf

# forbid access to the entire filesystem by default
<Directory />
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

# use .htaccess files for overriding,
AccessFileName .htaccess
# and never show them
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

# List of resources to look for when the client requests a directory
DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var

### 'Main' server configuration #############################################
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#
Include /etc/apache2/default-server.conf


# Another way to include your own files
#
# The file below is generated from /etc/sysconfig/apache2,
# include arbitrary files as named in APACHE_CONF_INCLUDE_FILES and
# APACHE_CONF_INCLUDE_DIRS
Include /etc/apache2/sysconfig.d/include.conf


### Virtual server configuration ############################################
#
# VirtualHost: If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs-2.2/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.
#
Include /etc/apache2/vhosts.d/*.conf


# Note: instead of adding your own configuration here, consider 
#       adding it in your own file (/etc/apache2/httpd.conf.local)
#       putting its name into APACHE_CONF_INCLUDE_FILES in 
#       /etc/sysconfig/apache2 -- this will make system updates 
#       easier :)
```

Comment: "what is changing the document root to point somewhere" => The Apache2 configuration is. You can find it in `/etc/httpd`. What files are in that directory? If there is a `httpd.conf`, then append it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved this by uncommenting the RewriteBase / line in .htaccess.

Sounds really simple but I've never needed to do this in Drupal before.

Comment: ok, it is solved then.. close it (mark this as the right answer) :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want localhost url to exectute index.php. Add the following to your httpd conf file and restart the httpd.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

I assume your apache server is configured properly to execute php. The config you posted isn't very usefull because the conf is mostly of include conf and less of actual configs. Well if my assumsion is right then DirectoryIndex should solve it. Read more on DirectoryIndex at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex